# How can be noted in this line of the Makefile that you need to collect information for debugging?

Tags: makefile

I want to compile the project and run it in the debugger. There is the following line in the Makefile:

```
 all: build_libs $(TARGET)
```

Can i specify -g option of gcc in this line? Or it should be somewhere else?

All contents of the Makefile are bellow.

```
SDK_PATH:=$(shell pwd)/../../ARDroneLib
PC_TARGET=yes
USE_LINUX=yes

ifdef MYKONOS
   include $(ARDRONE_CUSTOM_CONFIG)
   include $(ARDRONE_BUILD_CONFIG)
else
   include $(SDK_PATH)/Soft/Build/custom.makefile
   include $(SDK_PATH)/Soft/Build/config.makefile
endif

ifeq "$(RELEASE_BUILD)" "yes"
   ARDRONE_TARGET_DIR=$(shell pwd)/../../Build/Release
else
   ARDRONE_TARGET_DIR=$(shell pwd)/../../Build/Debug
endif

TARGET=video_opencv

SRC_DIR:=$(shell pwd)/../Sources

# Define application source files
GENERIC_BINARIES_SOURCE_DIR:=$(SRC_DIR)

GENERIC_BINARIES_COMMON_SOURCE_FILES+=\
Video/pre_stage.c\
Video/post_stage.c\
Video/display_stage.c\
image_processing.c\
controls.c

GENERIC_INCLUDES+=                  \
    $(SRC_DIR) \
    $(LIB_DIR) \
    $(SDK_PATH)/Soft/Common \
    $(SDK_PATH)/Soft/Lib

GENERIC_TARGET_BINARIES_PREFIX=

GENERIC_TARGET_BINARIES_DIR=$(ARDRONE_TARGET_DIR)

GENERIC_BINARIES_SOURCE_ENTRYPOINTS+=           \
   ardrone_testing_tool.c

GENERIC_INCLUDES:=$(addprefix -I,$(GENERIC_INCLUDES))
GENERIC_INCLUDES+=`pkg-config --cflags opencv`

GENERIC_LIB_PATHS=-L$(GENERIC_TARGET_BINARIES_DIR)
GENERIC_LIBS=-lpc_ardrone -lrt -lgtk-x11-2.0 -lcairo -lgobject-2.0 -lgdk-x11-2.0 -lm `pkg-config --libs opencv`


SDK_FLAGS+="USE_APP=yes"
SDK_FLAGS+="APP_ID=linux_video_demo"

export GENERIC_CFLAGS
export GENERIC_LIBS
export GENERIC_LIB_PATHS
export GENERIC_INCLUDES
export GENERIC_BINARIES_SOURCE_DIR
export GENERIC_BINARIES_COMMON_SOURCE_FILES
export GENERIC_TARGET_BINARIES_PREFIX
export GENERIC_TARGET_BINARIES_DIR
export GENERIC_BINARIES_SOURCE_ENTRYPOINTS

# Bug fix ...
export GENERIC_LIBRARY_SOURCE_DIR=$(GENERIC_BINARIES_SOURCE_DIR)


.PHONY: $(TARGET) build_libs

all: build_libs $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):
    @$(MAKE) -C $(SDK_PATH)/VP_SDK/Build $(TMP_SDK_FLAGS) $(SDK_FLAGS) $(MAKECMDGOALS) USE_LINUX=yes
    mv $(ARDRONE_TARGET_DIR)/ardrone_testing_tool $(TARGET)
    mv $(TARGET) $(ARDRONE_TARGET_DIR)/

$(MAKECMDGOALS): build_libs
    @$(MAKE) -C $(SDK_PATH)/VP_SDK/Build $(TMP_SDK_FLAGS) $(SDK_FLAGS) $(MAKECMDGOALS) USE_LINUX=yes

build_libs:
    @$(MAKE) -C $(SDK_PATH)/Soft/Build $(TMP_SDK_FLAGS) $(SDK_FLAGS) $(MAKECMDGOALS) USE_LINUX=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like if you add `GENERIC_CFLAGS = -g` to this makefile, it should work.  However, the real work of compilation is not being done by this makefile, it's being done by a makefile in the subdirectory `$(SDK_PATH)/VP_SDK/Build` (note how the `$(TARGET)` rule re-invokes make in that subdirectory with the `-C` flag).  So we can't know exactly what needs to be done by looking at this makefile.